# Converting Excel to PDF in c# using Office 2003

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, excel-2003

Anyone please help me in Converting Excel to PDF in c# code. I have Microsoft Office 2003 is installed in server.I have the code which works in Microsoft Office 2010. Since **XlFixedFormatType**  is not supported in 2003, I am failing there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UDC;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //using Excel; in VS2003

namespace ExcelToPDF
{
class Program
{
    static void PrintExcelToPDF(string ExcelFilePath)
    {
        //Create a UDC object and get its interfaces
        IUDC objUDC = new APIWrapper();
        IUDCPrinter Printer = objUDC.get_Printers("Universal Document Converter");
        IProfile Profile = Printer.Profile;

        //Use Universal Document Converter API to change settings of converterd document
        Profile.PageSetup.ResolutionX = 600;
        Profile.PageSetup.ResolutionY = 600;

        Profile.FileFormat.ActualFormat = FormatID.FMT_PDF;

        Profile.FileFormat.PDF.ColorSpace = ColorSpaceID.CS_TRUECOLOR;
        Profile.FileFormat.PDF.Multipage = MultipageModeID.MM_MULTI;

        Profile.OutputLocation.Mode = LocationModeID.LM_PREDEFINED;
        Profile.OutputLocation.FolderPath = @"c:\UDC Output Files";
        Profile.OutputLocation.FileName = @"&[DocName(0)] -- &[Date(0)] -- &[Time(0)].&[ImageType]";
        Profile.OutputLocation.OverwriteExistingFile = false;

        Profile.PostProcessing.Mode = PostProcessingModeID.PP_OPEN_FOLDER;

        //Create a Excel's Application object
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

        Object ReadOnly = true;
        Object Missing = Type.Missing; //This will be passed when ever we don’t want to pass value

        //If you run an English version of Excel on a computer with the regional settings are configured for a non-English language, you must set the CultureInfo prior calling Excel methods.
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        //Open the document from a file
        Excel.Workbook Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath, Missing, ReadOnly, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing);

        //Change active worksheet settings and print it
        Excel.Worksheet Worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Workbook.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.PageSetup PageSetup = Worksheet.PageSetup;

        PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;

        Object Preview = false;
        Worksheet.PrintOut(Missing, Missing, Missing, Preview, "Universal Document Converter", Missing, Missing, Missing);

        //Close the spreadsheet without saving changes
        Object SaveChanges = false;
        Workbook.Close(SaveChanges, Missing, Missing);

        //Close Microsoft Excel
        ExcelApp.Quit();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string TestFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TestFile.xls");
        PrintExcelToPDF(TestFilePath);
    }
  }
}
```

Microsoft Excel 97 or above, Microsoft Visual Studio 2003 or above is required. This is from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a56b093b-2854-4925-99d5-2d35078c7cd3/converting-pdf-file-into-excel-file-using-c).

Comment: Thank you, will have a look into this. :)